# How can I put a border around the page?

Tags: css

I am trying to work out how I can put a border around my page. Here is my html and css:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Royal Aura club</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restyle.css" / >
</head>
<body>
<main id="main">
<div id="header">


<h1> Royal Aura club</h1>

<div id="nav">
         <div class="navitem"><a href="#">Home</a></div>
         <div class="navitem"><a href="#">Restaurant </a></div>
         <div class="navitem"><a href="#">Gallery</a></div>
         <div class="navitem"><a href="#">Guest list</a></div>
</div>       <div class="navitem"><a href="#">Job Vancancies</a></div>
            
<div id="content">  
            
            <div id="textblock">
            <h2>Why Royal Aura?</h2>
            
            <p>
            Royal Aura club and restaurant is located in Mayfair just a walk away from the Ritz.  
            We will guarantee you will have a ball of a time with our brilliant DJ playing the tunes while your sipping cocktails away and dancing the night away.
            <p>
            Aura is a glamorous and sophisticated club that has a beautiful decor to get the mood. If you fancy doing VIP in style drop us a e-mail, we will be glad to help. Not to mention our fabulous food dishes we serve are to die for.  
            Please make sure you e-mail us 24 hours before the day you want to come and party or dine.
            </p>
            
</div>



        



</body>
</html>

Css-


body     {
    front-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFFDED;
    border:0px;
    

     }




#main    {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     width: 280px;
     margin: 50px auto;
     border: 0px solid;
     
     } 

#header  {
    
     border-bottom:none
    

     } 

#content {
     padding: 6em 1em;
         border: none;
     margin: 20px;
     }

#footer  {
    
        } 






h1  {
    
    font: bold 1.5em Tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #826BA9;
    font-style: italic;
    background-image: url(relogo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 120px;);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 100px;
    }



.navitem {

        float: left;
        border-right: 3px solid #999999;
        border-top:1px solid #999999;
        text-align: left;
        
    }


#textblock   {
       background-color: #D4CAE2;   
       width: 300px;
       border: 4px solid #000000;
       padding: 10px 7px;
       float: left;
       font-size: 110%;
       text-align: left;
       height: 400px
        }


a:link {  
    text-decoration: none;
        color: #000000; 
        padding-left: 0.em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    float: right;
    
        }   




a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #826BA9;
      padding-left: 0.5em;
      padding-right: 0.5em;
      }

a:hover   {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #826BA9;
      background-color: #F4E8F0;
      display: block;
      }
```

Comment: Please try to post relevant sections only. Also, what kind of the border should it be? Please give some detail.

Comment: Hi sorry, i'm new to this site. I just want a black border around the whole page so everything can be centered. Does that make sense?

Comment: do you mean around whole page or a particular section?

Answer (score 11):

```
body {
border: 5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: This seems to cause the boarder to stick to the top of the screen when scrolling down!

Comment: @esoterik You solve that by adding height: auto;

Answer (score 5):

This is all you need to do:

```
html{
    border: solid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think `<main>` is a valid tag. Also, make sure to close your tags.

Replace this:

```
</body>
</html>
```

With this:

```
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And replace this:

```
<main id="main">
```

With this:

```
<div id="main">
```

Lastly, replace this:

```
#main    {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     width: 280px;
     margin: 50px auto;
     border: 0px solid;

     }
```

Wtih this:

```
#main    {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     width: 280px;
     margin: 50px auto;
     border: 1px solid red; /* width, style, colour */
     }
```

And change the border property accordingly.

If you want a border around the entire page, put that border property within `body{}` in your CSS.

Comment: Yes, there is a tag called `main`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Answer (score 3):

try this, wouldnt say its the proper way tho

```
body {
    background-color: green;
    border: 5px solid white;
    padding: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to adjust the properties to match your desired result, but this should place a border around your page.

```
#main {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: What happens if `#main` is smaller than the document height?

Comment: Hey, i tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I can see red on my textblock a litte and up the top of the image. Very stange. ANy more ideas?

Comment: By the user's HTML, it wraps the whole page content. So without seeing the other styles, my *assumption* is that would not be the case. However, you could use `body` instead of `#main` if that were the case.

Comment: It worked but half of the page has a border not all. The half bottom. What shall i do?

Comment: Did you see that your section `#main` element is not a `div`. I assume this is a typo. If you correct this and validate the rest of the page, things appear better.

Comment: Yes i noticed that. I have changed it. If put a </div> at the bottom of the page not no luck

Comment: You have several issues with your HTML and CSS. Without knowing the exact goal, it's tough to put you in the right direction. **Sam** has provided a good start.

Comment: I managed to get a border but the bottom bit is missing so i have a top,right, left border no bottom. If you guys know how to work out why let me know. You have been a great help all.